# Independent Random variables, identically distributed

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y,X$ be random variables defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$. Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are independent and identically distributed and the common distribution is continuous. Prove that
$\displaystyle P\{X<Y<Z\}=\frac{1}{3!}.$

My try: well I've done this in a particular case, and as the problem says, it's true when
$X, Y, Z$ have exponential distributions with parameter $\lambda$.  There it is easy because the problem reduces to calculating the integral
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}\int_{y}^{\infty}\lambda^{3}e^{-\lambda(x+y+z)}dz dy dx.$  But I don't know how to do it in general.  Any suggestions? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: ${\rm P}(X < Y < Z) = {\rm P}(X < Z < Y) =  \ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the integrand by the joint probability distribution $p_{XYZ}(x, y, z)$. Now $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, so

$p_{XYZ}(x, y, z) = p_X(x)p_Y(y)p_Z(z)$

besides they are identically distributed, so $p_X = p_Y = p_Z = p$. So I think you are back to almost the same calculations as you did in your particular case, the only property needed being

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p(x)dx=1$

Does that help?

Comment: The solution below is much, much more elegant. I'm ashamed!

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry rules the world, my friends... See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/uniform-distributions-probability/32951#32951).